# How to write Java RegEx for matching a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to include all names which are containing string as ABC at the starting.

e.g

```
ABC_project1
ABC_project2
XYZ-project1
```

`ABC_project1` and `ABC_project2` should be included.

Please suggest how to use java regular expression, for example [a-zA-Z]*-[0-9]+

Comment: This doesn't require any regex, use `String#indexOf` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the static method [`Pattern.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
Pattern.matches("ABC.*", "ABC_project1");  // true
Pattern.matches("ABC.*", "XYZ-project1");  // false
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I wanted in this particular format [a-zA-Z]*-[0-9]+ to use in Sonarqube

Comment: @Nandeesh Bijoor: "ABC.*" **is** regular expression. What are you asking for?